# Add HTML "required" in Grails Select Tag

Tags: grails, drop-down-menu

I am trying to add a select dropdown button option using the Grails select tag. I need to make this field required and I am unable to do so.

This is what I have so far.

```
<g:select class="form-control" name:"test" from=${[test1:"Test 1", test2: "Test 2"]} optionKey="key" optionValue="value" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add`required="required"` as an attribute. Most Grails tags will simply include additional attributes as HTML attributes.

For example:

`<g:select class="form-control" name:"test" from=${[test1:"Test 1", test2: "Test 2"]} optionKey="key" optionValue="value" required="required" />`

Will render a `<select>` element with the `required="required"` attribute on it. Depending on how you are validating the form that may be enough.

Answer (score 1):

grails select doesn't offer required prop. But you can work around by using Jquery validator.